# Relatively prime to c + non-relatively prime to c = relatively prime to c?

Tags: number-theory

If I take a positive integer, a, which is not relatively prime to a positive integer, c, and then add, to a, a positive integer, b, which is relatively prime to c. Is the sum of a+b relatively prime to c?

I thought this up earlier and couldn’t find any answers online.

Here’s a couple examples where this holds:

a=0, b=3, c=10, a+b=3 is relatively prime to 10;

a=6, b=3, c=10, a+b=9 is relatively prime to 10

Ps this is my first post on stack exchange so please let me know if I’ve asked the question incorrectly.

Comment: $3+2=5$, $c=10$.

Comment: 2 isn’t relatively prime (aka co-prime) to 10.

Comment: @ProofBoy Then $2+3=5$, if it's that important that $a$ comes first. However, the primes that $c$ shares with $a$ must all be different from the primes that $c$ shares with $a+b$.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrés showed, the statement does not necessarily hold (counterexample: $a=2,b=3,c=10$).

Some statements that do always hold are:

- $a+b$ is not divisible by $c$.
- $\text{gcd}(a,c)$ is relatively prime to $b$.